# How do I return my Form errors

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, email, subscription

My php runs but for some reason my variables are not being communicated. What am I doing incorrectly?  I am trying to relay the message through ajax and i can't seem to get any type of error or success message to pop up, no matter where I put it in my php..which leads me to believe that the problem lies inside my ajax/javascript functions. The ajax should place the message straight in the defined .  I also realize this has been asked before on here but I have truly looked at a lot of them and still can not figure out what's wrong. Thanks guys, sorry for the wall.

AJAX

```
<!-- Email -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // magic.js
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // process the form
    $('form').submit(function(event) {
        $('#sub_result').html("");

        // get the form data
        // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
        var formData = {
            'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : 'phEmail.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data        : formData, // our data object
            dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            encode      : true
        })
            // using the done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {

                // log data to the console so we can see
                console.log(data); 

                // here we will handle errors and validation messages
                if ( ! data.success) {

                    // handle errors for email ---------------
                    if (data.errors.email) {
                        $('#sub_result').addClass('class="error"'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#sub_result').append('<div class="error">' + data.errors.email + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }



                } else {

                    // ALL GOOD! just show the success message!
                    $('#sub_result').append('<div class="success" >' + data.message + '</div>');

                    // usually after form submission, you'll want to redirect
                    // window.location = '/thank-you'; // redirect a user to another page

                }
            })

            // using the fail promise callback
            .fail(function(data) {

                // show any errors
                // best to remove for production
                console.log(data);
            });

        // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
        event.preventDefault();
    });

  });
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$errors = array();      // array to hold validation errors
$data = array(); // array to pass back data
// validate the variables ======================================================
// if any of these variables don't exist, add an error to our $errors array

if(filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)
{
   $errors['email'] = 'Email is not valid';
}


if (empty($_POST['email'])){
$errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';
}
// if there are items in our errors array, return those errors============================
if ( ! empty($errors)) {
$data['success'] = false;
$data['errors']  = $errors;


} else {

//variables===============================================================================
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "ghostx19";
$password = "nick1218";
$dbname = "ghostx19_samplepacks";
$user = $_POST['email'];
// Create connection======================================================================
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    echo "Connection failed";
} 
//add user================================================================================
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (email)
VALUES ('$user')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Subscribed!';
} else {
    $errors['email'] = 'Error';
}
$conn->close();


// message to me==========================================================================
$to      = 'garvernr@mail.uc.edu';
$subject = 'New subscription';
$message = $_POST['email'];
$headers = 'From: newsubscription@samplepackgenerator.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: newsubscription@samplepackgenerator.com';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
//message to user=========================================================================
$to      = $_POST['email'];
$subject = 'Subscribed!';
$message = 'Hello new member,
    Thank you for becoming a part of samplepackgenerator.com. You are now a community member and will recieve light email updates with the lastest information.  If you have recieved this email by mistake or wish to no longer be apart of this community please contact nickgarver5@gmail.com
    Cheers!,
    -Nick Garver ';
$headers = 'From: newsubscription@samplepackgenerator.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: newsubscription@samplepackgenerator.com';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
// show a message of success and provide a true success variable==========================
$data['success'] = true;
$data['message'] = 'Subscribed!';
}
?>
```

HTML

```
  <!--  Subscription  -->
  <div class="container shorter">
    <div class="no-result vertical-align-outer">
      <div class="vertical-align">
        <form action="phEmail.php" method="POST">
          <!-- EMAIL -->
          <div id="email-group" class="form-group">
            <label for="email"></label>
            <input type="text" class="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
            <button type="submit" class="emailbtn">Subscribe</button>
             <span></span>
            <!-- errors -->
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
          <br>
          <br>
          <div id="sub_result">
          </div>
```

Comment: Use json encode in php and get json result in ajax response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use json_encode in your PHP becuase your data type is json and you are expecting the response in json format like that

```
if (!empty($error)){

// your stuff

$data['success'] = false;
$data['errors']  = $errors;
echo json_encode($data);
}
else {
// your stuff
$data['success'] = "SUCCESS MESSAGE";
$data['errors']  = false;
echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you forgot to encode your `$data` array. Do `echo json_encode($data);` just before your ending PHP tag(`?>`), like this:

```
    // your code

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    // show a message of success and provide a true success variable==========================
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Subscribed!';
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Since the echo is on the last line of code it's ok, but I prefer using exit(json_encode($data)); since you don't want any other output (by following code) in your respond.

Comment: @dnFer I don't think `exit()` is necessary here, because after `echo json_encode($data);` the script is terminating anyway.

Comment: As I said starting my comment, it's ok for now. ;). I just made my comment for awareness in cases where the script doesn't terminate by itself after sending the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Your php don't return any value, add a simple "echo" line at the end:

```
...
$data['success'] = true;
$data['message'] = 'Subscribed!';
}
echo $data['message'];
?>
```

And in js (if all the other code is correct) you receive the message.

Comment: My friend data type is json and OP using data.success in ajax succes etc

Answer (score 0):

Your php file doesn't send anything to the output.

Add a line
    `exit(json_encode($data));`
to your php file on the line where you want to return your reply.